# How can I bind additional data to a Telerik Kendo Drop Down List

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a Kendo drop down list.  It's set up with a location name as the text and a location ID as the value.  However, I have a third field that I need to have bound to the model (or at least returned in some way back to my controller).  Is there a way to bind additional data?  I've seen several places where additional data can be displayed in the drop down box via a template, but I couldn't find any examples of additional values being passed back to the controller.

The model being used by the drop down box has these fields:

- origLocationName
- origLocationID
- customerID

Currently, origLocationName is the text value displayed in the drop down and origLocationID is the value that's bound to the model and passed to the controller.  What I want is to be able to bind the customerID as well as the origLocationID when the user picks a selection from the dropdown box.

Here is my dropdown box:

```
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ddLocation)
                        .Name("ddLocation")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;", onchange = "onChange_ddLocation(this)" })
                        .OptionLabel("Select from List")
                        .DataTextField("origLocationName")
                        .DataValueField("origLocationID")
                        .BindTo(Model.locations)
                )
```

When the user picks a location, I can access the origLocationID in the controller like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CustomerDashboard(ModelCustomerDashboard model)
    {
        ...

        dash.ddLocation = model.ddLocation;

    ...

        return View(dash);
    }
```

How do I also pass the location's customer number along with their location ID?

A couple of notes.  (1.) I can't just pass a single ID and look up the location & customer ID. There are multiple customers for each location.  So a location ID of 123 might be in company ABC and company DEF.  I didn't design this and can't make changes to the database; just working with what I have.  (2.) I thought about combining the customer ID and location ID into one field, something like this: "CustID:ABC;LocationID:123".  Then I could parse ddLocation and get the two values.  I'd prefer not to do this because there are places where customer ID is not needed (some users can only see one customer) so the present setup of having just the location ID in ddLocation is working for them.  I'd prefer not to have to rewrite everything I've done already for that instance.

Example:

```
Dropdown Box
-------------
Visible Text     ddLocation     ddCustomer
Warehouse 1      123            ABC
Warehouse 2      456            ABC
Studio A         123            DEF

User selects the first item.

Controller
----------
model.ddLocation = '123'
model.ddCustomer = 'ABC'
```

Edit 1:

Here is the jquery called when the dropdown box is changed:

```
    function onChange_ddLocation(arg) {
    try {
        $("#dropDownSource").val("Location");
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you post back (or Ajax) to CustomerDashboard? Could you post the client-side code?

Comment: Thanks Win for your reply.  I do a simple form submit when the drop down changes.  I edited my question to include the code.  Let me know if you have any suggestions for me.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the front-end code?

Answer (score 0):

add new attribute in your model ModelCustomerDashboard, say e.g. customerOrigLocationID, which will be combination of customerID & origLocationID with some seperator like '-' or ';' (hyphen or semicolon).
Bind this customerOrigLocationID as DataValueField to the dropdown.
In backend you can alwaus split it with seperator and have the value.